# Running executable fortran code from C# and pass parameter to run the .exe

Tags: c#, fortran

I have a FORTRAN .exe file which runs and works ok, it will ask
user to input 1 or 2 and if 1 is entered it will do some calculation and if 2 is entered it does different kind of calculation.

I need to call this from C# code. I know how to run .exe file from C# but I can not pass 1 or 2 to the .exe
   I have used different method but with no luck.

```
static void Main(string [] args)
        {
           string FileName = @"C:\......sco.exe";

           process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(FileName,"3");
           Process.Start(process.StartInfo); }
```

I really appreciate if some one knows how to fix this problems. I am new to C# and I can not rewrite the Fortran code since it is too comelicated.

Thank you for reading this post

Comment: The second argument to the `ProcessStartInfo` constructor specifies the command line arguments, currently you are passing it a 3. Have you tried changing that 3 to a 1 or 2?

Comment: Yes I have tried that, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know C#, so I can't tell you how to do this in detail, but when running a fortran program from the command line, you can supply an extra file with arguments. Call it like this: `mypgrogram.exe<inputs.ans`

In your case, `inputs.ans` would contain a single `1` or `2`. You can put each additional argument that the program asks for on a new line in this file.

Comment: Thank you. Ive tried this in cmd but I was not to able to run the program. i did this on cmd mypgrogram.exe<1 Ive got a message saying "the system can not find the file specified". Any other idea?

Comment: First create a new file, say `file.txt`. Edit this file and put a single 1 in it. Then run your program with `myprogram.exe<file.txt`. This means that the program reads any inputs from `file.txt`, one row at a time, instead of prompting the user for them.